# Where is the surfaces panel?

Tags: modeling, texturing

[image]

Image showing what my Blender workboard looks like right now.

Comment: what is a surfaces panel? Btw how did you manage to move your right menu to the left like this? It is impossible to pull to the left in default file

Comment: The surfaces panel is a panel in Material Properties. I cannot answer the second question because I do not know... I downloaded a preset for the head and it was just like that.

Comment: You need to select that top one material or add new one to have access to material settings, at this moment in the screen you have not selected any material, without material you cannot access it's settings

Comment: I have done that, I just forgot to show that in the screenshot :/

Comment: can you send that file to me here? use https://blend-exchange.com/ or something